# Can't locate a library when script is run from a different directory

Tags: python, shared-libraries, putty

Running a script on Putty, under directory `user/Projects/Python/example.py`.

Under the `Python` directory, there is a subfolder called `crypto`, and under that, a library called `cryptolib.so`.

If I run `example.py` from the Python folder, it works perfectly. But if I run it from my `user` folder, it says:

`OSError: ./crypto/cryptolib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

This is a C++ library I'm calling, using Python

How do I change the library path?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to import a module from another directory. This question [already has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder#comment53217573_4383597). An alternative solution is to copy and paste your file from one directory into another directory (this is terribly lazy and inefficient time-wise and storage-wise, but if you don't care about efficiency or writing Pythonic code, this may suit you).

Comment: I'm not trying to import another file, there is a library for which the path isn't specified. I want to change that. All other commands I've seen online regarding LD_LIBRARY_PATH haven't worked